# IOS uitableview cell selected background

Tags: ios, uitableview, background

I have a UItableview in my IOS app with some information in it. I changed the Selected background color to clearcolor using the following code:

```
UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[bgColorView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
[bgColorView release];
```

There is text and 2 images in the cell, I've build this using CGRectMake.
But When I select and hold a table cell the the images disappear behind what looks like a white background.

[image]

As you can see I'm holding the "Dacnusa sibrica" cell, how can I fix this?

Comment: How do you add your images to the cell?

Comment: I'm adding the images using var1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:var2]; and [cell.contentView addSubview:var1];

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to disable the blue selection of cells you can also set the cell's selection mode instead of modifying the background:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone
```

This simply disables the blue selection when tapping the cell but still allows the cell to be selected (and thus handled by code).

Answer (score 1):

With Auto layout it is possible to define **Selection=None** (default is gray) in the Interface Builder.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

have you used [cell.contentView addSubview:image]?
 use [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
for deselecting the cell

Comment: Yes I used [cell.contentView addSubview:image], where do I place [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES]; ?

Comment: It works now using the code TriPhoenix gave me but thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: ok...btw...we use deselectRow.. in selectedRowAtIndex method so that it doesn't remain selected once clicked.